# Magento 2 - Store disable issue in Multi stores website

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.2.5, store-view

I am working on multi store website, as far I know person should be able to disable store view / website if that is not a default store view / website.

I want to disable some of the store views but can't able to disable the store. it give me the notification

> It cannot be disabled

P.S: I already set one of the store view as default.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: Magneto version please

Comment: Magento EE 2.2.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update**

### **Things to check:**

1. Ensure that store views are not configured as any defaults.

**Website Scope**

[image: Website Showing Default Store]

**Store Scope - AKA: Store Group**
[image]

2. Ensure that config.php is not using the store view

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/config-php.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/config-files.html

3. Ensure that the configuration is not locked

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-sens.html

4. Check changelogs to see if issue was resolved in upgraded versions:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html

5. Query database to see values:

```
 select * from store;
 select * from store_group;
 select * from store_website;
```

---

Resources:

- https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/stores-all-create-website.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-configphp.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/config-reference-sens.html

---

I'd be willing to bet that it is related to bugs that are resolved in 2.2.6

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.6EE.html#theme

Try upgrading magento `composer update` in a test environment

Comment: Can you share more specific detail of bug fix in 2.2.6 in your answer by fetching it from your reference link? it would be helpful for other readers as well

Comment: Great Detailed Answer, upvoted and accepted your answer as well.